# Adding a dependency service while getting rid of Autofac - Open Source project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I am trying to help out an Open Source project ([Planet Xamarin](https://planetxamarin.com)) by migrating their current website to use .Net Core.

I got super far, and finished UI for all the pages, as you can see in the GIF [here](https://twitter.com/Saamerm/status/1373190526149791749).

However, since I haven't implemented Autofac, it's not getting the Feeds (NewCombinedFeedSource.cs) and Authors (IAmACommunityMember.cs) data that they were using to populate everything through Autofac before as you can [see here](https://github.com/planetxamarin/planetxamarin/blob/master/src/Firehose.Web/AutofacModules/FeedsModule.cs):

```
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
               .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IAmACommunityMember>())
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<NewCombinedFeedSource>()
               .AsSelf()
               .SingleInstance();
```

I don't think Autofac is needed anymore, and I was wondering if there's something I can just add inside `ConfigureServices` function of my `Startup.cs` to get this up and running.

What am I missing, what resources can help me? I tried to go through [this MS Dependency tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but they seemed to do things differently.

Note: I added this line `services.AddSingleton<NewCombinedFeedSource>();` to prevent a crash from occuring.

Comment: @Nkosi any recommendations ?

Comment: So I take it you want to use the stock DI? What is the error/issue you are encountering?

Comment: The stock DI is a little limited compared to the tried and tested 3rd party extensions like Autofac. You can still do things yourself but that requires a bit of work on your end using reflection to find and register your types.

Comment: @Nkosi thank you very much for your help, you pointed out the right direction! I have a slightly related RSS feed question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764502/rss-feed-using-writeto-to-update-an-existing-textsyndicationcontent (sorry for the spelling error earlier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stock DI is a little limited compared to the tried and tested 3rd party extensions like Autofac.

You can still do things yourself but that requires a bit of work on your end using reflection to find and register your types.

While I suppose your solution works for you, I would suggest you still register the types with the container and have them managed by the container instead of initializing them yourself.

Here is a simple example

```
public static IServiceCollection AddFeedSource(this IServiceCollection services) {        
    Type serviceType = typeof(IAmACommunityMember);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(serviceType);
    IEnumerable<Type> types = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                where serviceType.IsAssignableFrom(type)
                      && !type.IsAbstract
                      && !type.IsInterface
                select type;

    foreach (Type type in types) {
        services.AddSingleton(serviceType, type);
    }

    services.AddSingleton<NewCombinedFeedSource>();

    return services;
}
```

With this extension you now call

```
services.AddFeedSource();
```

in `Startup` using the default DI container.

this allows `IEnumerable<IAmACommunityMember>` to be used for constructor injection, as it was in [`NewCombinedFeedSource`](https://github.com/planetxamarin/planetxamarin/blob/master/src/Firehose.Web/Infrastructure/NewCombinedFeedSource.cs#L29).

```
public NewCombinedFeedSource(IEnumerable<IAmACommunityMember> tamarins) {

    //...

}

//...
```

Comment: This sounds like a much better solution than mine. Will give it a spin and update you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use reflection as @Nkosi mentioned to get the list of authors without using Autofac. And I realized that I didn't even need one of those

```
private IEnumerable<IAmACommunityMember> GetAuthors()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IAmACommunityMember));

    var types = assembly.GetTypes();
    var authorTypes = types.Where(t => typeof(IAmACommunityMember).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
        !_interfaceNames.Contains(t.Name));

    foreach (var authorType in authorTypes)
    {
        var author = (IAmACommunityMember)Activator.CreateInstance(authorType);
        yield return author;
    }
}

private string[] _interfaceNames =
{
    nameof(IAmACommunityMember),
    nameof(IWorkAtXamarinOrMicrosoft),
    nameof(IAmAXamarinMVP),
    nameof(IAmAMicrosoftMVP),
    nameof(IAmAPodcast),
    nameof(IAmANewsletter),
    nameof(IAmAFrameworkForXamarin),
    nameof(IAmAYoutuber)
};
```

Comment: While I suppose this works for you, I would suggest you still register the types with the container and have them managed bye the container instead of initializing them yourself. I'll see If I can whip up a simple example.