# RSS feed- Using WriteTo to update an existing TextSyndicationContent

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, rss

I'm helping out with [an open-source project](https://planetxamarin.com). In it, we are getting [a feed](https://www.planetxamarin.com/feed) (open using Chrome) using `var feed = new SyndicationFeed(...){...};` that contains different article titles along with their names.

[After that](https://github.com/planetxamarin/planetxamarin/blob/master/src/Firehose.Web/Infrastructure/NewCombinedFeedSource.cs#L164) I am able to iterate through the feed using `foreach(var item in feed.Items){}` and in there I can get the Title & Name string using `item.Title.Text` & `item.Authors[0].Name`.

The problem is that these properties are read-only, but I want to be able to add some text to the end of the Title property. So, the only way to update the Title (since it's of type `TextSyndicationContent`) seems to be by using `item.Title.WriteTo()`

How I can use the WriteTo to update the value of the existing Title without creating a new RSS Feed? Also, how can I get the outerElementName & outerElementNamespace?

I have added a screenshot of what the function requires me to put in.
[image: Screenshot of what autocomplete recommends that I put in]

Is the outerElementName "title" and outerElementNamespace "group? If so, what can I put in as XMLWriter to update the value of title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Title` property can be set on the item.

Create a new instance of `TextSyndicationContent` and copy over the title with the additional text.

```
//...

string newTitleText = item.Title.Text + "Some extra text content";

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Title.Type)) {
    string type = item.Title.Type == "text" ? "Plaintext" : item.Title.Type;
    TextSyndicationContentKind textKind = (TextSyndicationContentKind)
        Enum.Parse(typeof(TextSyndicationContentKind), type, ignoreCase: true);
    item.Title = new TextSyndicationContent(newTitleText, textKind);
} else {
    item.Title = new TextSyndicationContent(newTitleText);
}

//...
```

Comment: Hey @Nkosi, you are amazing, can't believe I missed that! I tried your solution but Im getting a System.Argumentexception on this line `TextSyndicationContentKind type = (TextSyndicationContentKind)Enum.Parse(typeof(TextSyndicationContentKind), item.Title.Type, ignoreCase: true);` saying "Requested value 'text' was not found." Any ideas why, I don't understand where 'text' is coming from?

Comment: Ok figured it out. I was trying to use the constructor enum to recreate the  type via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication.textsyndicationcontentkind?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 but will need to add a condition for plain text

Comment: @Saamer fixed it.

Comment: Holy moly, you're a genius. What's your GitHub/linkedin/Twitter ? I'd love to give you a shoutout

Comment: @Saamer Glad to help. I like keeping a low profile so shoutout is not necessary. Thank you anyway. Happy coding.